# getting typeof from angularjs $parse

Tags: angularjs

So I understand that $parse creates a function from a string, like $parse('name') will return the name property from a given object. My question is if it can somehow  also return the type of said property, something like:

```
var getType = $parse('typeof name');
var test = getType({name: 'Name1'}); //should be 'string'
```

Comment: For the limitations of expressions that can be parsed read [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$parse service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) does not evaluate the JavaScript `typeof` operator. If you wish to use `typeof` in an AngularJS expression, create a `typeof` function and add it to scope.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($parse) {
    var getType = $parse("typeof(name)");
    var typeofFn = x => typeof x;
    var test = getType({name: "Name1", typeof: typeofFn});
    console.log(test); //prints "string"
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
</body>
```

For the limitations of expressions that can be parsed read [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example $pase give you a setter/getter option.

And then use `typeof`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to know what type is the value the getter is using.

Using the getter you get a string in this case.

```js
var Controller = function($parse) {
  var vm = this
  var getter = $parse('user.name')
  var setter = getter.assign
  var context = {
    user: {
      name: 'AngularJS'
    }
  };
  
  setter(context, 'newValue')
  var test = getter(context)
  
  if (typeof test == "boolean") {
    console.log("boolean logic")
  } else if (typeof test == "string") {
    console.log("string logic")
  } else if (typeof test == "number") {
    console.log("number logic")
  } else if (typeof test == "undefined") {
    console.log("undefined logic")
  }
  
  // IT is a string
  vm.test = "typeof= " + typeof test

};
Controller.$inject = ['$parse']

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', Controller);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller as vm">
  {{vm.test}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm asking if I can get the type within the $parse function. I realize I can get it from the result of the function, but that doesn't help me, my string to parse is more complex and i need to do different operations inside it based on the property type.

Comment: Check now the example you can add your logic for any case you want